# "Invalid column" error populating GridView from SqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to read data from the database, then populate the datatable before binding to GridView.

When I run the application, it produces these erors:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name  'PrescriptionNumber'.
Invalid column name 'PrescriptionNumber'.
Invalid column name 'DrugCode'.
Invalid column name 'PrescriptionDate'.
Invalid column name 'PaymentStatus'.
Invalid column name 'AmountPaidFrom'.

Source Error: 


Line 34:           cmd.Connection = con;
Line 35:           con.Open();
Line 36:           using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
Line 37:           {
Line 38:               if (reader.HasRows)
```

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdpayment" runat="server" Width="876px" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" 
        BorderWidth="3px" style="margin-right: 288px" 
        onselectedindexchanged="grdpayment_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Did any want know am am doing wrong?
here is my table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payment](
[PrescriptionNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TreatmentCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DrugCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[PrescriptionDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[DrugQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,
[PaymentStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[AmountPaid] [money] NOT NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

C# Method that read data from the data:

```
 public void makepayment(string prescriptionValue)
    {
      DataTable storedata = new DataTable();
      string _connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connection);
      string sqlquery =
           "Select PrescriptionNumber,DrugCode,PrescriptionDate,PaymentStatus,AmountPaid"
         + "From Payment where PrescriptionNumber='" + prescriptionValue + "'";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery,con);
      SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      adapt.Fill(storedata);
      grdpayment.DataSource = storedata;
      grdpayment.DataBind();
    }
```

i call the method like this:

```
protected void btnsearchprescripitionnum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtprescriptionnum.Text == "")
        {

            checkval.Text = "Enter PriscriptionNumber";
        }
        else
        {
            makepayment(txtprescriptionnum.Text.ToString());
        }


    }
```

Comment: It looks like the query you're passing to your SqlCommand specifies fields not present in the table.

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the columns listed in the error message ('PrescriptionNumber', 'PrescriptionNumber', 'DrugCode', 'PrescriptionDate', 'PaymentStatus', and 'AmountPaidFrom') are not actually present in the table being queried.

You need to verify that you are directing your query at the proper table, that there are no typos in your query, and that the columns actually exist in the table you're trying to query.

Comment: @jadrnel27,the table definately exist with the correct columns

Comment: @jadrnel27, i have edited my question.Add the full detail of the table and methods.

Comment: @kombo Wow, that's odd!  The only thing I can think of at this point is your connection string ("*ApplicationServices*") is not pointing you to the right database.  Do you have more than one instance / version of this database / table?  Like, a production, QA, and test.  Or an old, incomplete version of the Payment table somewhere?

Comment: However, @kombo, I don't see the code from your error message (`using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())` and all that).  Where does that get called?

Comment: i want to believe this is the problem:    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery,con);

Comment: it seem i do not need sqlcommand, SqlDataAdapter is the only needed.I will do more research